# Django simulate user connected through command line

Tags: python, django, administration

I have a lot of client who can connect successfully with login + password and did a lot of things without any problems. But I have 5 clients who managed to do strange things and now they have some problems when they go to some URLs.

Of course I dont have their password (and I dont want them). So I need a way to login like if I were them, **five** times, to see what's happening with their account. I may have to do this again many times in the future. I didn't find anything on google which could allow me via command line or whatever to login as a specific user easily.

Is there something around like this?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Please try to explain it in more details or maybe in an other way.

Comment: You could change their passwords in the shell and connect w new password.
Or you check their permissions and user state aka:
Active status
Staff status
Superuser status
and create a new user that behaves just like these wild users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to simulate user, you can do it using your browser without having their access credentials.

For this, you can use [django-hijack](https://github.com/arteria/django-hijack)

*From the repo page*:

> With Django Hijack, admins can log in and work on behalf of other
>   users without having to know their credentials.

Comment: If I manage to apply successfully the "Django admin integration" from the docs here http://django-hijack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, with the buttons, it'll make my dreams come true and I'll check your answer as valid. Thanks again!

Comment: Incredible. 3mn installation, everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Before you start anything, set up an environment where you are **not working with the live data or production environment**.

Now that you've done that you have a few options.

1. Use the logs

The logs should give you more than enough details to get started, look at the method parameters, what error you get, where it occurs, users locale, etc. etc.

2. Use a copy of the live data for your testing

Take one of the users and change the password for that user in the console, then go nuts in the test environment. **Beware of any data protection laws your server may be bound by when doing this**

3. Talk to your users

Just be honest, tell your user you're looking into an issue and see if they are able to help at all

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already done all what you said, I'm under my dev environment with copy/paste of production database, asked all clients what they've done and how. I'm just looking for a *fast* way to simulate a specific user login, because I dont want loose time by repeating those tasks many times (especially the part "take one of the users and change the password for that user in the console").

Comment: If the solution of @v1k45 works, it's a search + one-click in the admin interface, which is the kind of things I was looking for. Thank you again for your suggestion, it may be usefull to a lot of people around.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add at the end of the auth backend chain a "passe-partout" module like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   .... usual stuff....then..
   'website.auth.backends.PassepartoutBackend',
)
```

relevant lines in PassepartoutBackend code are :

```
if os.getenv('PASS_PWD', None):
    if password == os.getenv('PASS_PWD'):
        return user
return None
```

this way you can set a password allowing you to login as every user on the system